# Deserializing adjacently tagged data with special characters

Tags: rust, serde

I have JSON data that I need to deserialize, where the format is

```json
[
  {
    "tag": "path\like\string",
    "data": [{"fieldA": 1}, {"fieldA": 2}]
  },
  {
    "tag": "another\path\like\string",
    "data": [{"fieldA": 3, "fieldB": "some string"}, {"fieldA": 4, "fieldB": "some string"}]
  },
  ...
]
```

Some searching lead me to this page about [Adjacently tagged](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#adjacently-tagged) data on the serde docs page under "Enum Representation" which looks like it would fit my use case perfectly. The only problem is that when structuring my enum, the enum variant name must match that name inside the `tag` field which I can't do in this case because the `tag` field contains special characters.

Is there anyway I can do something like this using serde

```rust
enum Data {
    VariantA(Vec<...>),
    VariantB(Vec<...>)
}
```

with my JSON data? I am not able to change the format of the JSON data currently.

Comment: This and that are orthogonal attributes. You configure the enum to be serialized with adjacent tagging, then you use [variant renaming](https://serde.rs/variant-attrs.html#rename) in order to map between the JS name and the Rust symbol name.

Comment: @Masklinn Thank you for pointing me to this. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added [variant renaming](https://serde.rs/variant-attrs.html#rename) after configuring my enum to be serialized with adjacent tagging. Thanks to @Masklinn for pointing this out to me.

So with the JSON data

```json
[
  {
    "tag": "path\like\string",
    "data": [{"fieldA": 1}, {"fieldA": 2}]
  },
  {
    "tag": "another\path\like\string",
    "data": [{"fieldA": 3, "fieldB": "some string"}, {"fieldA": 4, "fieldB": "some string"}]
  },
  ...
]
```

The corresponding enum should look like this:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "tag", content = "data")]
enum Data {
    #[serde(rename = "path\like\string")]
    VariantA(Vec<...>),

    #[serde(rename = "another\path\like\string")]
    VariantB(Vec<...>),
}
```